I have upgraded angular version from 15 to 16 and material ui from 15 to 16. Facing issue in mat-card, ngModel,ngValue, mat-form-field and many
NG8001: 'mat-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.  

44         <mat-label class="font-weight-bold">Firmware Version</mat-label>

NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

45             <form [formGroup]="executionAnalysisFormGroup">
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


 NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

47               <mat-form-field style="width:200px">
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


NG8001: 'mat-select' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-select' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-select' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. 

48                 <mat-select formControlName="selectFWFormControl">



NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

49                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Firmware Version"  [(ngModel)]="fwInput"  (input)="filterFWOption($event)">


'mat-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.  

73         <mat-label class="font-weight-bold">Select Regression Status:</mat-label>

How to address above issues?
Package.json:
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.16",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^11.0.1",
    "blob-util": "^2.0.2",
    "bn-ng-idle": "^2.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "countup.js-angular2": "^7.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "echarts": "^5.5.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.2",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.8.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.7.2",
    "ngx-capture": "^0.12.2",
    "ngx-echarts": "^5.2.2",
    "ngx-loading": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.4.4",
    "ngx-spinner": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-treeview": "^10.0.2",
    "npm": "^8.1.3",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "sugar": "^2.0.6",
    "tslib": "^2.8.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }

